# Displayed with "\t" next to each observation

Tags: dataframe, data-cleaning, opencsv, read.csv, resource-cleanup

I tried to read a csv dataset file in R with read.csv but every observation is showing with a \t next to it (screenshot attached).

code: generate <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Datasets/ElectricGenerationCapacityandEnergy/Generation-Table1.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM",sep = ",")

I've tried specifying the separator (sep = ",") and file encoding (fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"). I have also tried the read.delim function and setting my working directory to the correct place. None of my attempts were successful. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjqhp.png)
Would appreciate any help with this one. Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the code you used to read the file? Adding some lines of the CSV file would also help.

Comment: this is the code I used to read the file.
generate <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Datasets/ElectricGenerationCapacityandEnergy/Generation-Table1.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM",sep = ",")

Comment: My guess is that those "\t" characters are from the CSV file. Would you mind copying a few lines from the file and add them here?

Comment: The gsub() function worked just fine to omit the \t. Thank you!